# RxJava how to cache static observable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I want to cache the following observable

```
val currentUser: Observable<User>
    get() = Observable.create { emitter ->
            ...
    }
```

Since the observable returned by `create` is static, I can't just call `cache` on it. The reason I am doing this is that the observable is accessed in different parts of the app, and I want it to immediately return the latest value, instead of making network calls every time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
val currentUser: Observable<User> = Observable.create { emitter ->
    ...
}.replay(1)
 .autoConnect(0)
```

?

Comment: What's autoConnect(0) mean? The observable is always connected?

Comment: Even if there are no subscribers, Observable retains last value, instead of being disposed.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for but didn't think possible in RxJava. Thanks a lot

Comment: When I found out this is possible. I think of this as the holy grail of RxJava

Comment: How about when user logs out and I do want it to be disposed, what should I do?

Comment: Uh. Probably just call `dispose()` on it and then let it die, and re-create it when there is an active user again. If the app is singleton, then the unfortunate way to model it would be to make this thing nullable. Basically, to dispose it, call `dispose()` on it, but then it won't work again and needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to EpicPandaForce, this is what I ended up using. I had to specify the emitter type otherwise there's error

```
val currentUser: Observable<User> = Observable.create { emitter: ObservableEmitter<User> ->
    ...
}.replay(1)
 .autoConnect(0)
```